# Retrieving json objects from python (using Django) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have been poking around the web but have not been able to find an example which works for me. It seems as though it is a simple mistake as I have seen multiple examples that are very similar, but when I try following these I keep getting errors (mainly `SyntaxError: invalid property id`).

Python code (in Django view):

```
my_dict = {'mykey' : 'myvar'}
jtest = json.dumps(my_dict)
context = {'form': form, 'test_dict' : jtest}

return render(request, "browsefiles.html", context)
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {{ test_dict }};
</script>
```

Error:

`SyntaxError: invalid property id`

If someone could help me find what is causing this error that would be greatly appreciated. I would like to access the dictionary in the in the javascript code segment.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd to access the dictionary in the in the javascript code segment. I plan to use variables in the dictionary to create new labels in the html using document.write().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will escape special characters in your page and the browser cannot recognize the object. You must mark it as safe for Django to leave it alone:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {{ test_dict|safe }};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, however it throws yet another error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: Can you go to "View Source" in you browser and see what django is putting after `var data = ...`

Comment: Ah, I did not realise the variables updated in the inspector. It is presenting the correct dictionary: var data = {"mykey": "myvar"}; But, it is working now, there was a stray curly bracket a couple of lines down that I did not notice which was causing the second error. However, the answer solved the initial problem, so thank you very much!